# Magento why only title prefix show on title area

Tags: magento-1.9, page-title

My projects default page title fixed. Suppose I go category page that's not show category name in title that showing default title which from `core_config_data` table path `design/head/default_title`.

Same things happen for product page and other pages.

how to possible to fixed this. And now I need to this dynamic

Comment: what do you mean by Fixed? Its static?

Comment: Semi static. It's come from `core_config_data` table where  path `design/head/default_title`. If I change there then My title changed

Comment: You can add the value for `Page Title` in the category page from admin panel.

Comment: But other pages? Any page not show any different title. All are fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find file `/app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTEMPLATE/layout/local.xml` and find

`<reference name="root">
    <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</reference>`

If You add this then your Title gone.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your `head.phtml` file you have do not have fixed title and it has dynamic value.

```
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
```

Check file

```
app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/page/html/head.phtml
```

Comment: I checked. That's Ok. If I change database value then my title changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can Add the `Page Title` in admin panel category page.

For a common page title you can give a value for `title prefix` in `system->Configuration->General->Design->HTML Head->title prefix`

Comment: I need dynamic `Page Title` but this showing only `title prefix`

Comment: Did you add the category page Title?
catalog->manage categories ->select a category and give a value to PAGE TITLE

Comment: It's not happen for only category pages. It's happen for all pages. I just give a example like category page.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
$currentCategory = Mage::registry("current_category");

//Display the current Category Title
echo $currentCategory->getName();
```

need to reindex and clear the cache.

> Note:- reindex requires.

**I hope this will help you.**